# C#, Visual Studio 2022 update, error after publishing - provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2022

There are a lot of similar questions here and I think I read all of them, but still haven't found the cause of this error:

> provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>
> provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

The code:

```
string connection = Properties.Settings.Default.SqlConnection; 

SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new() 
        { 
            ["Server"] = connection, 
            ["Database"] = "myDatabase", 
            ["Trusted_Connection"] = true 
        }; 

using SqlConnection conn = new(builder.ConnectionString); 

try 
{ 
    conn.Open(); 
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    throw;
} 
finally 
{ 
    conn.Close(); 
}
```

I store `myServerName\myInstanceName` in the settings:

```
<add name="TestSQLConnection.Properties.Settings.SqlConnection"   
     connectionString="Servername\SQL2012" />
```

This works on my local machine, but when I publish the application, the user will get the above mentioned error. If I log in and run the published application on the server, it works (but I am admin, so that is not a surprise) and strangely enough, after I run it, other users will be able to run it without error, but only temporarily (How is this possible?). I am having this issue since the latest update of VS2022, before that it worked and if I publish an older project now, the user gets the same error. All the applications I published earlier with the same connection string work just fine (which rules out most of the possible causes discussed here in earlier questions).

Things that I tried:

1. Make sure there is no typo in the connection string
2. Make sure that the server is reachable
3. Replace server name with IP in the connection string
4. Check if SQL Server Browser is running
5. Enable port 1433 in Server Configuration Manager
6. Add port 1433 to the connection string
7. Test applications published earlier with similar code (same connection string) and the same user.
8. Repair Visual Studio 2022

Any idea where should I try to look for the root cause would be highly appreciated. Can this be an issue with VS (I also tried to repair VS out of desperation, with no avail) or am I missing something trivial?

**UPDATE**

It is definitely an issue with the access rights. If I publish the application to a folder that is already in use for an application deployed before, it works. The funny thing is that there is no difference in security settings between the old and new folders. (same users/groups have the same access rights to the folders)

Comment: Have you tried entering the connection string manually as a hardcoded string? If this solves the issue, you simply have an issue with your App.config file access/copying/releasing. You can build a connection string for the check here: https://www.aireforge.com/tools/sql-server-connection-string-generator

Comment: @akseli Yes I did. Just to be sure I tested it again with the connection string generated by the tool you suggested (it's a nice tool btw) but I get the same result. With my account I can connect, with other user accounts I still get the same provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26